# Json don't update result in the seconde time

Tags: android, json

I have an activity where I can do a search through URL json file, so the 3 parameters pass from EditText of MainActivity to the second activity (annonces), the URL Json recovers the three values ​​and the results is normally displayed , but the problem if I made a return to MainActivity and I change the value of EditTexts and I click search, the results do not change.

this is my project :

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dzweber.waslup;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
AutoCompleteTextView cat;


String[] categories={"informatique","infographie","mathématique","Génie civil","Biologie"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(annonces.instance != null) {

            annonces.instance.finish();

    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    cat=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new
            ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,categories);

    cat.setAdapter(adapter);
    cat.setThreshold(1);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home) {

    }
    else if (id == R.id.login) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,login.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
     else if (id == R.id.avanced_search) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,avanced_search.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.annonces) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,avanced_search.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void as(View view) {
    EditText loc;
    EditText key;
    loc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a_loc);
    key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a_keys);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), annonces.class);
    intent.putExtra("ca", cat.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("lo",loc.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("ke", key.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void connect(View view) {

}
}
```

annonces.java

```
package com.example.dzweber.waslup;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class annonces extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
public static ArrayList<annonce_item> Items = new ArrayList<annonce_item>();

public static TextView txtv;
public static String data = "";
String skey = "";
String sloc = "";
String scat = "";

String date="";
String loc="";
String cat="";
String vue="";
String titre="";
String id="";
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;
public static annonces instance = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // fetchD p = new fetchD();
    //p.execute();
    instance = this;

    skey= getIntent().getStringExtra("ke");
    sloc= getIntent().getStringExtra("lo");
    scat= getIntent().getStringExtra("ca");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_annonces);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    new AsyncCaller().execute();

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testing);
    t.setText(scat);

    // String generate = "https://www.waslup.pw/generation-json";
    // String myurl = "https://www.waslup.pw/wp-content/uploads/wpdata.json";
    //  new MyAsyncTaskgetNews().execute(generate);
    //  new MyAsyncTaskgetNews().execute(myurl);





    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    instance = null;
}

public void buclick(View view) {

     }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.annonces, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.login) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,login.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.avanced_search) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,avanced_search.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.annonces) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}








class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<annonce_item> Items = new ArrayList<annonce_item>();

    MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<annonce_item> Items) {
        this.Items = Items;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return Items.get(position).ititre;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater linflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view1 = linflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_annonce_item, null);


        TextView id1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView date1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView cat1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.cat);
        TextView loc1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.loc);
        TextView titre1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.titre);
        TextView vue1 = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.vue);
        date1.setText(Items.get(i).idate);
        id1.setText(Items.get(i).iid);
        cat1.setText(Items.get(i).icat);
        loc1.setText(Items.get(i).iloc);
        titre1.setText(Items.get(i).ititre);
        vue1.setText(Items.get(i).ivue);

        return view1;

    }


}


















 /*
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    new AsyncCaller().execute();

}*/

private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(annonces.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("/tChargement des annonces en cours ... ");
        pdLoading.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.waslup.pw/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=do_ajax&fn=get_posts&count=10&key="+skey+"&cat="+scat+"&loc="+sloc);

            HttpURLConnection httpuc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputstream = httpuc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

            String line ="";
            while(line != null){
                line = bf.readLine();
                data= data + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = null;
            JA = new JSONArray(data);
            annonces.Items.removeAll(annonces.Items);
            for (int i=0 ; i<JA.length();i++){
                JSONObject JO =(JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                date =""+ JO.get("date");
                loc =""+ JO.get("loc");
                cat =""+ JO.get("Cat");
                vue =""+ JO.get("vue");
                titre =""+ JO.get("title");
                id =""+ JO.get("Id");

                annonces.Items.add(new annonce_item(id,date,loc,cat,vue,titre));


        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }




        return null;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        final MyCustomAdapter myadpter = new MyCustomAdapter(Items);

        ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listannonce);
        ls.setAdapter(myadpter);
        ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView titre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titre);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), titre.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                myadpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                TextView id2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), annonce_details.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_from_annonces_activity", id2.getText());
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Have you debug your code and checked that every time you are moving to annonces activity you are getting proper results from intent?

Comment: No, how i can do it ?

Comment: here you can have tutorial about how to debug code in android studio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCM2ee200n8

Comment: i try it but it dosn't work :(

Comment: i think that the problem is in AsyncTask, it run just one time
because the values of the EditTexts are changing

Comment: Share your full code with me i can compile and debug it for you then we will be able to solve the problem

Comment: sorry,
this is my project code 
https://www.4shared.com/zip/1-hbBohwda/Waslup.html

Comment: you can use in localisation the words " oran " , " alger " 
for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code and solved your problem.

There are two things need to discuss.

1. Your API providing the results according to localisation.If we change first two fields results will remain same and web service is fetching only one item with localisation 'oran'. But if we change localisation from 'oran' to 'alger' web service is displaying 4 results.
2. Here is the problem in your code.You are not concatenating your results properly in your data string. I have updated your code and now your code of AsyncCaller in announces Activity should be like:

> Here is the code

```
 private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(annonces.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("/tChargement des annonces en cours ... ");
        pdLoading.show();
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.waslup.pw/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=do_ajax&fn=get_posts&count=10&key="+skey+"&cat="+scat+"&loc="+sloc);

            HttpURLConnection httpuc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputstream = httpuc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            JSONArray JA = null;
            JA = new JSONArray(total.toString());
            annonces.Items.removeAll(annonces.Items);
            for (int i=0 ; i<JA.length();i++){
                JSONObject JO =(JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                date =""+ JO.get("date");
                loc =""+ JO.get("loc");
                cat =""+ JO.get("Cat");
                vue =""+ JO.get("vue");
                titre =""+ JO.get("title");
                id =""+ JO.get("Id");

                annonces.Items.add(new annonce_item(id,date,loc,cat,vue,titre));


        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("js_ex:",e.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("io_ex:",e.toString());

        }




        return null;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        final MyCustomAdapter myadpter = new MyCustomAdapter(Items);

        ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listannonce);
        ls.setAdapter(myadpter);
        ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView titre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titre);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), titre.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                myadpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                TextView id2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), annonce_details.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_from_annonces_activity", id2.getText());
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }
```

}

> In this code i added this part

```
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line).append('\n');
        }

        JSONArray JA = null;
        JA = new JSONArray(total.toString());
```